# confusion about a python recursion function

Tags: python, recursion

I got a `print_backward` function code online, but I am so confusing
about how it works and its output.

The below is my code.

```
def print_backward(num):
    if num == 10:
        return 
    num += 1
    print(num)
    print_backward(num)
    print("yeah")   
    print(num)
    print()

print_backward(6)
```

The below is output.

```
7
8
9
10
yeah
10

yeah
9

yeah
8

yeah
7
```

I can understand how it prints from 7 to 10, since each time it call
recursively, num += 1.

But I am confusing, once num achieves 10, the `print_backward` should
return, then done. It should not print yeah 10, yeah 9, yeah 8, yeah
7. Why this code has called return, how it still can print? How this code works to print backward, which means why I called `print(num)`, it
can print from 10 to 7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the first runs, the code does not go further than the inner call to `print_backward(num)`, that is 4 times (like an infinite recursion)

When the argument reaches 10, all the functions return and it goes further, printing the original `num`+1 with which they were called.

The highest numbers are printed first because the calls where the number is higher return first.

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation. It is very clear.

Comment: Really appreciate your time.

Comment: no problem! those recursive calls are not very intuitive. Using a debugger can help sometimes.

Comment: Except using 'print', I don't know other ways to debug. Could you recommend me a debugger?

Comment: I like debug with prints :) I've tried `pydb` a couple of times and it's very similar to gdb. There's a new refactored version here: https://code.google.com/archive/p/pydbgr/downloads

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will check out all of them.

Answer (score 1):

Function call is actually a stack operation. And recursion is a special case of function call.

Every time you call a function, the Return Address will be push into a stack, and when the function return, the program will pop the Return address from the top of stack, and program continue to execute from there. You can have a look at the official description about `call stack` in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack).

For your example, `print_backward(7)` call first, and then the next command will push into the stack, and then when you call the `print_backward(8)`, the next command will be pushed into the stack again, so after 4 recursion call, the stack will be like this:

```
+-------------------------+ <--- Stack top
| num = 10, print("yeah") | \
| num = 9,  print("yeah") |  |
| num = 8,  print("yeah") |   >   Call stack
| num = 7,  print("yeah") |  |
+-------------------------+ /
```

The criteria hit the if condition `num == 10:` when calling from `print_backward(10)`. The program execute `return` statement, the `Return address` from the stack top will be pop, and program starts from there, that means, `print('yeah')` for num = 10 will be execute. After finished call for `print_backward(10)`, the stack will pop another Return Address from the stack, and `print('yeah')` in `print_backward(9)` will be executed. This operation will be ended when the stack is empty, that means ,there is no more function return.

Comment: Excellent explanation. Thank you so much, man. Very detailed, super clear.

Comment: Really appreciate your time.

Answer (score 0):

The function calling happens through stack.

You call print_backward on 6. So stack will have 6. 
Now you call it on 7 ---> So stack has 6,7 where 7 is top. 
Now you call it on 8 ----> So stack is 6,7,8 
Now on 9, So stack is 6,7,8,9 
Now on 10, So stack is 6,7,8,9,10.

Now when function returns , it pops from stack.  
So, you were in function with parameter 10. So, you called return and it gets popped from stack. Now stack is 6,7,8,9. 
Now it prints "yeah" and 10 (because num is 9 and we did num = num + 1 before). 
Now it returns and pops 9. Now stack is 6,7,8 
Now it prints yeah and 9 because num is 8 and we did num = num +1 before).

Similarly, it prints other as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Stack is good for me to understand how this code works. Really appreciate your time.

Comment: @OregonDuck : No problem

Answer (score 0):

For your case - `print_backward(6)` it took 4 calls (recursively) to hit return criteria i.e. `if num == 10` - during those calls the function printed:

```
7  # print_backward(6) - first call we made
8  # print_backward(7) - recursive
9  # print_backward(8) - recursive
10 # print_backward(9) - recursive - inner most, where the return is executed
```

For next recursive call `print_backward(10)` the return condition gets true, and the function starts returning (starting from the inner most call) - as result the lines below the recursive call (line 6) get called i.e.

```
yeah # 4th call (inner most) returned
10

yeah # 3rd call returned
9

yeah # 2nd call returned
8

yeah # 1st call returned
7
```

The call stack view visualization 'd be:

```
print_backward(6)
| 7 # num += 1 and then print(num)
| print_backward(7)
| | 8
| | print_backward(8)
| | | 9
| | | print_backward(9)
| | | | 10
| | | | | print_backward(10)
| | | | | | return 
| | | | yeah # print("yeah")   
| | | | 10   # print(num)
| | | | ()   # print()
| | | yeah
| | | 9
| | | ()
| | yeah
| | 8
| | ()
| yeah
| 7
| ()
```

Comment: It is an awesome graph and answer to my question. It makes me know the process of my code very well. Thank you so much so much, dude. It is really helpful. Really appreciate your time.

Answer (score 0):

when print_backward(6) is called then

```
1 check for 10
2 increase 6 by one num = 7
3 print 7
4 call backward with 7
```

for 6 print_backward is not completed yet and print_backward(7) is pushed on the top of stack. The remaining part

```
print("yeah")
print(7)
```

will execute at last when the recursive call is completed. I am skipping check 10 in the below steps. Will include that in last steps.

```
5 increase 7 by one num = 8
6 print 8
7 call backward with 8 (7 not completed)
8 increase 8 by one num = 9
9 print 9
10 call backward with 9 (8 not completed)
11 increase 9 by one num = 10
12 print 10
return is encountered  
13 call backward with 10 (9 not completed)
14 check for 10 and return. 9 will continue for the execution.
15 in the execution of 9 num is 10 so yeah is printed and then 10 is printed and print_backward for 9 is completed. Similarly for 8 num is 9 which print yeah followed by 9 and so on.
```

Comment: Nice explanation. Step by step, very easy to follow and understand. Thank you so much. I believe I get deeper understanding to recursion. Really appreciate your help and time.